# Formula for Autocorrelation

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation, autocorrelation, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings

I have time-series data generated via Metropolis algorithm - Monte Carlo simulations. I need to know correlation between data points generated given by $r_k = c_k/c_0$ where $c_0$ is the variance of the sample. For $c_k$, I have two formulas:
$$c_k = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{n-i}(x_i - \mu)(x_{i+k} - \mu)$$
and,
$$c_k = \frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{i=1}^{n-i}(x_i - \mu)(x_{i+k} - \mu)$$

I have plotted for both $c_k$ and the only anomaly that I got was in using the second formula for $c_k$ was that few of the correlation coeeficients were greater than $1$.

I don't know which formula to use in which case and why. If you could explain this, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first formula, with divisor N, is usually used.  It is slightly biased, but generally has smaller mean square and gives an autocorrelation function which is positive semi-definite.  This means, for example, that if you estimate autoregressions using the Yule Walker equations, you always get a solution. There is detail in, for example, Priestley's book "Spectral Analysis and Time Series" around p 323.